# Run multiseat using AMD & Nvidia GPUs?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, radeon, multiseat, dual-graphics

I recently bought an RX 480 4GB to go with my Ryzen 2600 build.  I want to run dual GPUs, for me that I can run 2 monitors under normal work, and for my roommate that he can play PC games.

I tried setting up multiseat a couple months ago. It surprised me that this functionality seems so hard to accomplish.

Comment: Hello, may I ask about the process you used to try to set up multiseat?  Trying to setup multiseat using xorg configuration files is ridiculously difficult.  Using loginctl is relatively simple if you're used to the command line.  I have a GUI called EasySeats, which makes it even easier.  If you're still attempting to take advantage of that kind of functionality.

EasySeats is on github if you would like to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I have an RX 480 in the x16 slot and a GT 710 in the x8 (maybe x4) slot. WHen I rebooted with the RX 480 replacing a GTX 750 Ti, no nvidia drivers were loaded in the software update list, and the RX worked fine.

Rebooting after adding the GT alongside the RX card, the nvidia drivers loaded again, and the RX gave me no trouble.